# MariaDB / Wordpress High CPU Suggestion

Tags: mysql, wordpress, vps, mariadb-10.3

I have an old website with 5K posts and 14K photos, website not used for 3 years. Now i want to reactive it. Database is  about 250mb. I am using Wordpress. I cleanedup and update everything also the theme. Its now very fast and stable with online 20-30 users. But when i try to login admin panel for edit or create a post, it's starting using %200-300 cpu. Can you advise for MySQL settings. I couldnt fix it myself.

**VPS Specs:** E5-2650v2 (4-CORE) - 8GB Memory - SSD Disc / This VDS using only for this website.

```html
Conf File:

performance_schema=on
tmp_table_size=512M
max_heap_table_size=512M
table_open_cache_instances=16
table_open_cache=2000
table_definition_cache=1000
innodb_log_file_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
max_connections=100
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0
```

```html
Tuner Output:

perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.19 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.3.17-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log(11K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log contains 7 warning(s).
[!!] /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log contains 6 error(s).
[--] 3 start(s) detected in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
[--] 1) 2020-06-14  7:13:47 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2020-06-14  7:11:03 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2020-06-14  7:03:30 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
[--] 1) 2020-06-14  7:13:44 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2020-06-14  7:11:01 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2020-06-14  7:03:18 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 291.0M (Tables: 276)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 43m 29s (56K q [21.557 qps], 1K conn, TX: 280M, RX: 23M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 90% / 10%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 7.6G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 3.7G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 1.8G global + 18.9M per thread (100 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 95M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 2.1G (27.89% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 3.7G (48.46% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/56K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 15% (15/100)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/1605)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 2K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 82% (6K on disk / 7K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (15 created / 1K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 98% (396 open / 402 opened)
[OK] table_definition_cache(1000) is upper than number of tables(435)
[OK] Open file limit used: 5% (59/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (30 immediate / 30 locks)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 95.1M
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.
 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 4 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.3.17-MariaDB)
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (24M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/123.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 93.3% (30 cached / 2 reads)
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 1.0G/291.0M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 128.0M * 2/1.0G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 8 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.99% (155610176 hits/ 155627037 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 96.94% (39155 hits/ 40391 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1236 writes)
 
-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[!!] Aria pagecache hit rate: 91.1% (74K cached / 6K reads)
 
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
 
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
 
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
 
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: OFF
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: OFF
[--] This is a standalone server
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys for MySQL
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/FromDual/mariadb-sys for MariaDB
```

Comment: Which process(es) is/are using the CPU? I'm assuming MySQL given the context of your post. You might try installing the Query Monitor plugin to see if any tables or queries are suspect. In the past, I have had luck with deleting and recreating the indexes on wp_posts and wp_postmeta (which seem to be unusually susceptible to getting fragged), though you might want to take the site down temporarily while doing this (or clone the tables). Do you have caching with something like Redis or Memcached?

Comment: Not using Object Cache, only using WP Fastest Cache Plugin with CDN. I will try to setup object cache. I will try get some information via Querry Monitor then share them.
Querry Monitor:
Object Cache
95.5% hit rate (6,863 hits, 325 misses)
External object cache not in use
The Redis extension for PHP is installed but is not in use by WordPress
Opcode cache in use: Zend OPcache

Comment: You can `sudo apt install redis-server` on Ubuntu or `sudo yum install redis` on RPM and then install the very excellent [Redis Object Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/) plugin.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @danielh  After installing and activating Redis. Mysql CPU usage instantly decrease. Thanks.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck Today i restartedservices too many times so i will share details tomorrow. After activate Redis cache, MysqlTuner start suggesting increase read_buffer to 2M

Comment: There are some areas MST we can discuss after 24 hours of a typical day's work.  That is why we ask for minimum 24 hours uptime.  Thanks

Comment: If you have not already done so, you may still want to check your table indexes to verify that they are as they should be.

Comment: @danielh       Your contact form at danhendricks.com is not working.  Please view profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: @BurakKüçük  Do you use the FEDERATED engine for anything?  If not, there is no reason for it to be available - as listed on the MySQLTuner report.  And FEDERATED is no longer supported on some versions.